# error parsing xml unbound prefix/

Tags: xml, parsing, namespaces, prefix

i am new to android app development and i am getting these errors. can anyone help me out please

error parsing xml unbound prefix

attribute is missing the android namespace prefix

this is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android="@+id/frontpagelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ushop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="93dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="@string/ushop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This attribute:

```
android="@+id/frontpagelayout"
```

Doesn't have a namespace prefix (such as `android:`) and you haven't defined namespace for it explicitly with an `xmlns` attribute.

Looking at examples in the [first result I got when googling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), it should be an `id` attribute:

```
android:id="@+id/frontpagelayout"
```